# Integer to String, How can I fix the following error: "TypeError: Can't convert undefined to object"?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, math

I am trying to convert my integer from **numGenerated** to a String. That way I can add it into an HTML el to show on screen.

Whenever I run the code, it returns `undefined` when I use `toString()`, or **TypeError: can't convert undefined to object**, when I split the **numGenerated**.
I have tried using the `toString()` function, but I get `undefined` thrown back.

```
var numGenerated;
var x = (document.querySelector("#generated_number").innerHTML = "".split
  .call(numGenerated, "")
  .join(""));

function highLow() {
  var storeNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 0;
  numGenerated = storeNum;
}
```

I expect to get a string returned, which can be used in an HTML element to show a result.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Betting Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="betting.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cash_total">
      <p>Your balance is: <span id="amount"></span>.</p>
    </div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">BET NOW</h1>
    <div class="bet_amount">
      <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
      <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
      <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
    </div>
    <div id="generated_number"></div>
    <div class="buttonHolder" style="text-align: center;">
      <button id="lower">LOWER</button> <button id="higher">HIGHER</button>
    </div>
    <script src="betting.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML code

Comment: Just added it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You don't call `highLow()` anywhere, and `numGenerated` never gets a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in this line:

```
var x = document.querySelector('#generated_number').innerHTML = "".split.call(numGenerated,"").join("");
```

You're assigning a variable to an assignment of another variable - you don't even need `x`. Remove `var x =`, and then to fix the next error, place the line inside a function:

```
function updateDisplay() {
    document.querySelector('#generated_number').innerHTML = "".split.call(numGenerated,"").join("");
}
```

Working demonstration:

```js
var numGenerated;

function updateDisplay() {
  document.querySelector('#generated_number').innerHTML = "".split.call(numGenerated, "").join("");
}

function highLow() {
  var storeNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 0;
  numGenerated = storeNum;
}

highLow();
updateDisplay();
```

```html
<div class="cash_total">
  <p>Your balance is: <span id="amount"></span>.</p>
</div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">BET NOW</h1>
<div class="bet_amount">
  <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
  <button class="ten" value="10">10</button>
  <button class="fifty" value="50">50</button>
  <button class="hundred" value="100">100</button>
</div>
<div id="generated_number"></div>
<div class="buttonHolder" style="text-align: center;">
  <button id="lower">LOWER</button>
  <button id="higher">HIGHER</button>
</div>
```

The above snippet calls both functions manually, but it would make sense to bind them to a button click like so:

```
<button id="random" onclick="highLow()">Randomise</button>
<button id="update" onclick="updateDisplay()">Update Display</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the job.
Do you also have an explanation as to why .toString() 
and 
"".split.call(numGenerated, "").join("");

Give different errors? Don't they essentially do the same thing?